# How to get all option values with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

```
<select>
<option>test</option>
<option>test1</option>
</select>
```

In fact I'm going to retrieve the innertext of `<option>`,but these two jobs are similar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var opt_vals = [];
$('select option').each(function() {
   opt_vals.push(($this).text());
});
```

Comment: You need to write $ outside from brackets. It shows error.

Answer (score 9):

```
values = $.map($('select option'), function(e) { return e.value; });
alert(values.toString());
```

Comment: Most elegant. I just got this thing with global variables, but it's great anyway.

Answer (score 5):

```
$("select option").each(function() { 
    $(this).text(); //do something with this text
});
```

or if you want a concatenated string of all options then its simply

```
$("select option").text();
```

if you want values - as in value attribute of option (`<option value="x">text</option>`) then replace the `text()` function in the code above with `val()`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var values = $("select option").map(function() { alert($(this).val()); });
```

Demo here http://jsfiddle.net/subodhghulaxe/Zmebr/

Answer (score 0):

With the HTML you provided, I'd just use this:

```
var opt_vals = $('select').text().trim().split('\n');
```